# How to filter and format the data from input function in Python?

Tags: python

When I define a struct in C, I can use the `scanf` function to get and format the data from standard input.

For example:

```
struct date { int day; int month; int year;}; 
struct date today;

scanf("%i/%i/%i", &today.day, &today.month, &today.year)
```

But how could I get the same function in Python if I have already define a new class? I have tried to compose a code but it's too long. Could you please introduce a simple way?

Comment: This is not anyway related to C!

Comment: Write the function in a file and use it by `import`. This will simplify to some extend.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
class Date(object):
    def __init__(self, day=None, month=None, year=None):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year

val = raw_input("Enter date in day/month/year format: ")
vals = val.split("/")
today = Date(*vals)

print "{}/{}/{}".format(today.day, today.month, today.year)
```

Gives:

```
% python filterformat.py
Enter date in day/month/year format: 14/02/2016
14/02/2016
```

Comment: I might suggest using `input` instead of `raw_input` to exclude non-integers; you can always deal with the exceptions then.

Comment: Very good hint, but how can I directly get the data from format "14/02/2016" instead of inputting them independently? And it's still too long compared with "scanf" function in C, isn't it?

Comment: @Junchoon I've updated the answer to accept all the values in one string, but there's no real python equivalent to `scanf`: `raw_input` (or just `input` in python3) is the best you can really do

Comment: @NolenRoyalty, thank you very much. That's one I wanted!

Comment: @Junchoon if that's the answer you were looking for, feel free to accept my answer to indicate that the question has been answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with bells and whistles, use them:

```
import datetime as dt

# input for python3, raw_input for python2
datestr = input('Please enter a date using this format: %d/%m/%Y')
date = dt.date.strptime(datestr, format='%d/%m/%Y')

print('You entered {:%d/%m/%Y}'.format(date))
```

See the datetime docs for more info:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module. From the docs:

> This will try to parse a date from the given string, attempting to detect the language each time.

The `parse` function will parse almost any standard date format, and return a datetime object from a given string, where datetime is standard and built into python.

Usage for date input from user:

```
import dateparser
date_from_user=input('Enter a date') 
datetime_obj=dateparser.parse(date_from_user)
print(datetime_obj.year, datetime_obj.month, datetime_obj.day)
```